# Keep UIStackView to be positioned exactly below, top UIStackView inside a proportional UIStackView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, uitextview, uistackview

I have This one big CustomView, on which I have positioned one parent `UIStackView` to contain two `UIStackView`s.

Each of these `UIStackView` are set to contain two items each to fill equally.

The first `UIStackView` contains two `UITextView`, while the second one contains two `UIImageView`.

What I'm trying to aim is I'd like to make the bottom `UIStackView` which is the one that contains the `UIImageViews` to keep its position to being directly aligned below the `UITextView` from the top that has the highest height.

I want it to be just like that no matter how long the `UITextView` height grows.

Here is a screenshot of my CustomView.xib.
[image: CustomView.xib]

It should look into something like this:

[image: Goal view]

Or like this:

[image: or]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close to what you want - just a few changes...

Stack Views are great, except they don't always behave well when designing them in Storyboard / Interface Builder. In this case, to get your desired result, the Text Views must have Scrolling disabled. Unfortunately, IB goes crazy when you do that.

So, you have to *start* with Scrolling **enabled** while designing your view, and then disable it via code when your view loads.

For your "parent" vertical `UIStackView`, constrain it to leading, top and trailing edges - no bottom or height constraint. Set it to `Alignment: Fill`, `Distribution: Fill`, and, so you have a little vertical buffer between the text and images, `Spacing: 10`.

The horizontal `UIStackView` containing your text views should be `Alignment: Fill`, `Distribution: Fill Equally`, and `Spacing: 8`.

The horizontal `UIStackView` containing your image views should be `Alignment: Top`, `Distribution: Fill Equally`, and `Spacing: 8`. Give each image view an appropriate Aspect Ratio constraint - in the image below, the images are `200x300` pixels, so I set the ratio to `2:3`.

IB will also complain that the stack view *needs a constraint for Y position or height*. This is not really correct, but IB is failing us here. So, give the left-side text view a Height constraint - doesn't really matter what you use (I used a Height of 160). The key is to set the Priority on that constraint to Low (250). That will hold it in place and satisfy IB during design, but will *not* prevent the text view from auto-sizing to its content.

Your storyboard should now look like this (I set the view background to Blue so we can see the layout):

[image]

Now, in your view controller code, you need this:

```
class StackTVViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textViewLeft: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var textViewRight: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textViewLeft.isScrollEnabled = false
        textViewRight.isScrollEnabled = false

    }

}
```

When you run the app, you will see this result:
[image]

Now, add two more lines in `viewDidLoad()` to change the text in the text views:

```
class StackTVViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textViewLeft: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var textViewRight: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textViewLeft.isScrollEnabled = false
        textViewRight.isScrollEnabled = false

        textViewLeft.text = "The left-side text field now has short text."
        textViewRight.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    }

}
```

and, if you've set the constraints correctly, you'll see this:
[image]

***Note:*** At this point, you can even edit the text views, and their heights will auto-adjust when you add / delete enough text to change the line wrapping!

Comment: you're a lifesaver. This is what I was trying to do exactly. I just had to tweak the image heights a bit and that's the only change I altered from these steps.

Comment: btw @DonMag can you explain why setting height constraint on one of the UITextView fixes the issue on the IB?

Comment: @JojoNarte - well, I'd classify it as a "bug" in IB. Without that height constraint, the app will run as desired, and auto-layout **won't** throw any errors. I've come across several issues with IB - *particularly* with Stack Views. Best guess is simply that there are differences in the way auto-layout runs constraint resolution in IB vs as runtime.

Answer (score 0):

you will add to upper stack constrains 0 , 0 , 0 from top and left and right , and bottom stack 0, 0 ,0 from bottom and left and right 
[image]

and constrain between 2 stack will be 
[image]

, or you can use 4uiview that hav equal width

Comment: This would result on the UIImages UIStackView to be positioned to the top overlapping the UITextView.